# Show Random Page

Tags: android, kotlin

How To Change activity according to condition?

For Example, the click Button open `Mainactivity4`, but next time, click Button Show `Mainactivity2`, And Not Ever Previous Pages(not show `mainactivity4` and `mainactivity2`)

Comment: That has nothing to do with Kotlin, and everything to do with android. Tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In the `onCreate()` method of your activity:

- create a list containing the classes of the activities to open
- create a list of shuffled numbers beginning from 0 to the size-1 of the previous list
- initialize a variable that will iterate through the list of numbers, each time picking the next.
- set the listener of the button

  ```
  val activities = listOf(
      MainActivity1::class.java,
      MainActivity2::class.java,
      MainActivity3::class.java,
      MainActivity4::class.java)

  val numbers = (0 until activities.size).shuffled()

  var counter = 0

  button.setOnClickListener {
      if (counter >= activities.size) counter = 0;
      val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity, activities[numbers[counter]])
      startActivity(intent)
      counter++
  }
  ```

If you want to stop opening any activity after they are all opened, 
change the `if` statement inside the listener to:

```
if (counter >= activities.size) {
    // show a toast ???
    return;
}
```